# Brining multiple versions of a project into git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've just started using GIT and currently have 2 versions of the same project (Staging and Production).

I want to bring my projects into GIT (using a BitBucket Repository) and want to compare the current Staging Server projects with the ones on the Live Server.

I've copied a project from the Live Server into what I'm going to call my Development Box, and created a Repository for this project.

I now need to be able to initialise Git on the Production Servers Project, and point it to my Repository. How is this done?

I eventually want to have a Production Branch, which I can push on to my Production server, and a master branch for the Live Server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I have 2 versions of the same website. I've made several changes to the live site, and added several other changes on the development site. I now want to put both versions into GIT under 2 branches (Development and Live)

Comment: I think you're looking for `git subtree` command.